# Mule- Iterating through a Map in dataweave and skipping duplicate elements

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to to iterate database query result in dataweave and skip duplicates as well as few elements based on some condition. Say, if vales for a column **order** is coming like:
**10-ord, 11-ord, 12-ord, I should be picking up only 11-ord and skip any other rows which value ends with -ord.**

Rest of the values which does not end with -**ord** should be picked up.

The current code gives distinct element but not the above highlighted condition. The current code is :

```
payload map ((payload, indexOfPayload) -> {
id: payload.orderId ,
number: payload.orderNumber
}) distinctBy $.number
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **filter**, **distinctBy** and **or** clause you can achieve it

```
%dw 1.0
%var payload = [
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "10-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "11-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "11-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "12-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "13-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "14"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "14"
    }
]
%output application/json
---
payload filter (not($.orderNumber contains '-ord')) or $.orderNumber =='11-ord' map ((payload, indexOfPayload) -> {
    id: payload.id ,
    number: payload.orderNumber
}) distinctBy payload.orderNumber
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "id": "value",
    "number": "11-ord"
  },
  {
    "id": "value",
    "number": "14"
  }
]
```

Duplicate values and values with **-ord** are removed except one

Comment: Good answer, use the in-built `distinctBy` feature of dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it based on the "filter" clause. I built a sample logic demonstrating your case below:

```
 %dw 1.0
%var payload = [
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "10-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "11"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "12-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "13-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "14-ord"
    }

]
%output application/json
---
payload filter (not ($.orderNumber contains '-ord') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter before mapping for better performance. Try following filter for your requirement

```
payload filter ($.orderNumber contains '-ord') and $.orderNumber == '11-ord' map ((payload, indexOfPayload) -> {
id: payload.orderId ,
number: payload.orderNumber
})
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 1.0
%var payload = [
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "10-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "11-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "11-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "12-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "13-ord"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "26"
    },
    {
    "id":"value",
    "orderNumber": "26"
    }
    ]
%output application/json
---
payload filter (not ($.orderNumber contains '-ord')) or $.orderNumber=='11-ord' map ((payload, indexOfPayload) -> {
    id: payload.id ,
    number: payload.orderNumber
}) distinctBy payload.orderNumber
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both contains or the substring login like [3..5] matching ord and filtering the JSON objects.